# Swift In-Out Parameters - use case

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I recently learn about "In-Out Parameters" in Swift and I have question to you.

What are use case when "In-Out Parameters" is better than e.x. func that return value that you can assign to var?

Thank you for help.

Comment: One good examlpe is operators: http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/operator/plseq/ look at att the `+=` defenitions. I would not say using `+=` is better than `+`, but it's less code. One more example would be all the methods, that are not written with functional style, so mutable state is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good use case for `inout` parameters is the `swapTwoInts` function provided by [The Swift Programming Language](https://itun.es/it/jEUH0.l).

```
func​ ​swapTwoInts​(​inout​ ​a​: ​Int​, ​inout​ ​b​: ​Int​) {
​    ​let​ ​temporaryA​ = ​a
​    ​a​ = ​b
​    ​b​ = ​temporaryA
​}
```

Given

```
var a = 0
var b = 1
```

you can easily call

```
swapTwoInt(&a, b: &b)
```

### <s>Scenario 2: without inout params</s>

On the other hand, without `inout` parameters the function should be written as follow (more compact actually)

```
func swapTwoInt(a: Int, b: Int) -> (a:Int, b:Int) {
    return (a:b, b:a)
}
```

but the use would require 3 lines of code instead of 1:

```
let swapped = swapTwoInt(a, b: b)
a = swapped.a // was swapped.b, fixed as suggested by Martin R
b = swapped.b
```

### Considerations

As you can see, in *Scenario 2* part of the logic of the function needs to be written outside of the function itself. This is not good because it creates an overhead of code to be written each time the function is called.

Comment: *"but the use would require 3 lines of code instead of 1: .."*  – Not really: `(a, b) = swapTwoInt(a, b: b)`.

Comment: Btw, your last example does a "double swap", to `a` and `b` are as before :)

Comment: @MartinR: you are totally right. Should I delete my answer?